# Does it make sense for my Federal Wages and SS wages to be the same if I have nonzero DD values for insurance?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, form-w-2

On my W2, I had $xx,xxx listed in both my Federal Wages as well as my SS and Medicare wages. My tax software running it's data checks said it was unusual since I had values in Box 12 (of which, I had multiple, specifically: codes AA, C and DD).

Did my employer miscalculate my federal wages on my W2?

Comment: Are those _all_ of the codes you have? None of those reduce your taxable income AFAIK.

Comment: edited for clarity. Those are the only box 12 codes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ;[codes you mention](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/fw2.pdf) (AA, C and DD mean the following):

> AA—Designated Roth contributions under a section 401(k)plan
>
> C—Taxable cost of group-term life insurance over $50,000(included in
> boxes 1, 3 (up to the social security wage base), and 5)
>
> DD—Cost of employer-sponsored health coverage. The amount reported
> with code DD is not taxable.

The Code AA doesn't change box 1,3 or 5.
The code C adds the same amount to box 1,3,and 5. unless you are above the social security maximum

Code DD doesn't impact box 1,3,5